# piping through a headless vi-style editor

Tags: pipe, vi

I know `vi` well.  I would really like to use it when I'm piping around on the command line.

Is there an easy way to pipe the stdout of a process into a headless version of vi kind of thing and then to stdout?

Something like this:

```
$ uname -a | <headless_vi> "3f D"
Linux robbie 4.8.13-1-ARCH
```

Comment: I'm hoping there's an obvious built-in solution for this.  It seems so useful.

Comment: There is actually an answer to this, but: (a) This is called _stream editing_ and there's a tool that is actually named `s`tream `ed`itor that does stream editing. (b) vim has a scriptable command-driven mode, which _one has to be using anyway_ in order to get the script-by-simulating-keyboard-input mechanism to write to standard output.

Comment: You *can* use `vi` for this.  See ["How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?"](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/4676) on the vi/Vim stack exchange.

Comment: @Wildcard Not for doing screen editing (using the `f` command, for example). `vi` additionally requires standard input to be a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As @JdeBP points out, you are better off using the `sed` stream editor, or maybe even just `cut`:

```
$ uname -a | cut -d ' ' -f 1-3
OpenBSD box 6.0
```

Or, if you cut the editing out of it completely,

```
$ uname -snr
OpenBSD box 6.0
```

The problem with `vi` is that it doesn't have a stream editing mode.  The line editor `ex` *does* have a "batch mode", but this is seldom used, and it, like any other line editor, can't be made to "move the cursor back and forth" on a line.

`sed` is a stream editor version of the line editor `ed`, specifically tailored for applying editing scripts to streams. The `vi` editor is the screen editor version of the line editor `ex`, and the `ex` editor is a further development of `ed`.

The `vi` command sequence `3f␣` would move to the 3rd `␣` (space) on a line and the following `D` would delete the rest of the line. Handy, if you have screen editing capabilities.

In `ed`, `sed` and `ex`, you either add lines, delete lines, or change lines, with "lines" meaning "whole lines at a time".  To do the equivalent thing in `ed` or `ex`, assuming we're at the correct line in the buffer, you would say... well, you would have to craft a regular expression pattern and replacement string and use them with the `s` editing command to change the line, which in this case is non-trivial.

With `sed`, this would take the form

```
$ uname -a | sed 's/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/'
```

Comment: [The way to do this that I alluded to](http://blog.robertelder.org/use-vim-inside-a-unix-pipe-like-sed-or-awk/) involves `-c` to run vim-only `ex` commands, in particular `:normal` and `:write`.

Comment: @JdeBP Ah, Vim. Vi will still refuse to even _start_ when standard input is not a connected to a terminal.